# linux | synchronize uid and gid

Tags: linux, uid

I'm really new about linux so this question is pretty dumb i know. Sorry for that.

I checked the user and group and some of users' uid and gid are different so 
I just wanna make them synchronized.

```
tail -6 /etc/passwd

mysql:x:993:1000::/path
apache:x:1000:1001::/path
user1:x:1001:1002::/path
```

I'm wondering that it's not the matter if I synchronized uid and gid. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you could manually synchronize them in the /etc/passwd file (and then manually update every affected file to the new uid/gid), there is no reason to worry about making the uid and gid the same for each user.

Typically, when people talk about synchronizing uid/gids they are referring to ensuring user accounts on two seperate computers for the same user have the matching uids and matching gids (ie. the two uids match and the two gids match).